# Using yeoman-generator variable inside generated template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I am generating an angularJS project with yeoman. I call the generator with an argument and I get it from my main generator's script (index.js) by doing:

```
this.argument('name', { type: String });
```

I can use this parameter inside this same index.js by using:

```
this.options.name
```

Question: I want to use this same this.options.name inside my template, so that i can give its value to a variable. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an angular constant and set it to this value. Then inside the controller associated to this view, just inject this constant.

```
myApp.constant('YEOMAN_NAME', MYVALUE);
```

Then just inject your constant inside the controller associated to your view, associate this constant to a scope variable and use it inside your template.

Now the "hardest" part is how to get this value inside the angular environment.

I don't know what is your index.js, I suppose that is only the main script associated to your page. 
In this case, if you do inside the main script something like

```
this.myVariable = 'myValue';
```

You are actually creating a new attribute to the window object (if you are not doing that inside some function)

So what you could do is to associate this variable to a window parameter, and try to be most specific as possible so you are not on risk to override something else in the window, like:

```
window.myYeomanName = this.options.name;
```

Then you can define your constant inside angular everywhere just doing:

```
myApp.constant('YEOMAN_NAME', window.myYeomanName);
```

Comment: Thnak you very much, I'll try it out and let you know if it worked. What if I want to access a variable from Node.js?

Comment: Do you mean that you have your node.js app server side and your angularjs app client side?

Comment: Yes, I do @quirimmo. I want to access Yeoman's generator variables from both the angularjs and the nodejs sides

Comment: After you have them on one side, you can easily get them also on the other side. For example if the above solution works for angularjs, then you can send an AJAX request to your node and send these variables to node.js 

Does it make sense?

Comment: What i need is to create a module with a database connection. The name of this database connection is custom, so what I want to do is to call the generator with a parameter (this.options.name) and then create a modules with a connection = this.options.name

Comment: sorry but the question was how to use a yeoman variable inside the template in angular, here things are going a bit over :D Can you explain me better all your flow please? so starting from the generation with yeoman all the steps automation in the correct order that you want to achieve

Comment: Your answer seem to be correct for what I was asking at first, so I checked it as a correct solution

Answer (score 3):

To access a yeoman variable from Node.js, I did the following:

I renamed the file connections.js from sails, renamed it to _connections.js and placed it at the same level than sails folder inside the folder "templates" from yeoman's generator. Leaving it like this:

```
> yeomanGeneratorFolder 
>   |-app   
>      |-index.js   
>      |-templates
>        |-sails
>        |-_connections.js
>        |- ....
```

On the Generator's index.js. I created a function to write on a js file the data I needed. I sent a JSON object inside the copyTpl() function which contains the data I will need in the new file:

```
connections() {
      this.fs.copyTpl(this.templatePath('_connections.js'), this.destinationPath('./config/connections.js'),
      {
        dbName: this.item.dbName
      });
    }
```

In _connections.js I wrote:

```
database: '<%=dbName%>' //optional
```

Notice **dbName** is the key I gave to the JSON I sent inside the copyTpl() function in index.js.